# Why did an HTTP request return lines giving an expiration date in 1984?

Tags: http, request

I am working through Chapter 12 of the Python for Everybody course, and when I ran the code for an HTTP request, in addition to getting the expected information, I also got these lines:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
 Pragma: no-cache
 Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
```

I have no idea what they mean, or if this means I made an error of some kind. Any explanation anyone can offer for this strange message from pre-1984 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an arbitrarily old date that in combination with the other headers should cause no client to cache the response, ever, and always issue a new request for that resource.